# Start index error while doing Code First Migration

Tags: migration

I am trying to add fields from VB.Net class file to SQL database, while doing "Add Migration" It is showing "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdHAz.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message when i tried to make a migration. The cause in my case was an empty value for `MigrationId` for a particular migration in the `_MigrationHistory` table.

This field must have a value in the same format as the string parameter of the attribute `[Migration("YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_SeedData")]`, which is described in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most of all you have some class in your data project with attribute `Migration` (maybe for seeding data or something similar) which name is not in expected format like this:

```
[Migration("YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_SeedData")]
```

Adjust the migration name to be in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_Description` format to fix the error `startIndex cannot be larger than length of string`.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite a control freak when it comes to names.

I always remove the timestamp from the beginning of the name of migration files.

Migrations are executed in alphabetical order anyway, and I prefer using a suffix rather than a prefix.

However, the value of the **Migration** attribute in the "designer" file must include the prefix, but it can be set to fourteen zeroes, which I like better than the timestamp.

So, here is what I usually do:

- I create a migration named Migration023.
- The files will be named

  - `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_Migration023.cs` and
  - `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_Migration023.Designer.cs`.
- I rename the

  - `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_Migration023.cs` file to
  - `Migration023.cs` and the
  - `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_Migration023.Designer.cs` file to
  - `Migration023.Designer.cs`.
- And I eventually edit the "designer" file to change the value of the **Migration** attribute as follows:

```cs
[Migration("00000000000000_Migration023")]
```